# Why does the ball in pong get stuck at the bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I recently made a JS Pong game. It works well, but the ball rarely gets stuck at the bottom or top. It looks like it is halfway through the wall and constantly bouncing. [Video of the issue happening.](https://youtu.be/HYZOhP7DFs0) You can try the game [here](http://msolonko.net/pong). I do not know why this issue is happening because the logic seems right and works 90% of the time correctly. Here are the main two functions of my program:

```
function moveAll() {
  if (showingWinScreen) {
    return;
  }
  computerMovement();
  ballX += ballSpeedX;
  ballY += ballSpeedY;
  if (ballY <= 10) {
    ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
  } else if (ballY >= HEIGHT - 10) {
    ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
  }
  if (ballX >= WIDTH - 10) {
    if ((ballY > paddleY) && (ballY < paddleY + 100)) {
      ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
      var deltaY = ballY - paddleY - 50;
      ballSpeedY = deltaY / 5;
    } else {
      player1Score++;
      ballReset();
    }
  } else if (ballX <= 10) {
    if ((ballY > mouseY - 50) && (ballY < mouseY + 50)) {
      ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
      deltaY = ballY - mouseY;
      ballSpeedY = deltaY / 6;
    } else {
      player2Score++;
      ballReset();
    }
  }
}

function drawAll() {
  if (showingWinScreen) {
    colorRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, "black");
    canvas.fillStyle = "yellow";
    canvas.fillText("Click to continue!", 300, 300);
    if (player1Score == WINNING_SCORE) {
      canvas.fillText("You won!", 360, 500);
    } else if (player2Score == WINNING_SCORE) {
      canvas.fillText("The computer beat you!", 280, 500);
    }
    return;
  }
  colorRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, "black");
  drawNet();
  makeCircle(ballX, ballY, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, "red");
  colorRect(790, paddleY, 10, 100, "cyan");
  colorRect(0, mouseY - 50, 10, 100, "yellow");
  canvas.fillStyle = "white";
  canvas.fillText(player1Score + "    " + player2Score, 360, 100);
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Some approaches test to see if a collision will happen _before_ the movement is applied to it, taking appropriate action. This also allows for better collisions, since one can work out the time of collision (it rarely happens exactly at the time a frame is rendered - it occurs at some point between them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's only one case in which this could happen: when, in a colliding frame, you decrease the speed.

When the speed remains the same, no matter what, your ball will always bounce back to the previous' frames position:

```js
var cvs = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
var balls = [
  Ball(50, 50, 0, 5, 5, "red"),
  Ball(100, 50, 0, 5, 10, "blue"),
  Ball(150, 50, 0, 5, 15, "green"),
  Ball(200, 50, 0, 5, 20, "yellow")
];

var next = () => {
  updateFrame(balls);
  drawFrame(balls);
}

var loop = () => {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    next();
    loop();
  });
}

next();

function Ball(x, y, vx, vy, r, color) {
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    vx: vx,
    vy: vy,
    r: r,
    color: color
  }
};

function updateBall(b) {
  b.x += b.vx;
  b.y += b.vy;
  
  if (b.y <= b.r ||
      b.y >= cvs.height - b.r) {
     b.vy *= -1; 
  }
};

function drawBall(b) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = b.color;
  ctx.arc(b.x, b.y, b.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fill();
}

function updateFrame(balls) {
   balls.forEach(updateBall); 
}

function drawFrame(balls) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);
  balls.forEach(drawBall);
};
```

```html
<canvas width="300" height="150" style="background: #454545"></canvas>
<button onclick="next()">next</button>
<button onclick="loop()">run</button>
```

But when the speed changes, things get stuck:

```js
var cvs = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
var balls = [
  Ball(50, 50, 0, 10, 5, "red"),
  Ball(100, 50, 0, 10, 10, "blue"),
  Ball(150, 50, 0, 10, 15, "green"),
  Ball(200, 50, 0, 10, 20, "yellow")
];

var next = () => {
  updateFrame(balls);
  drawFrame(balls);
}

var loop = () => {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    next();
    loop();
  });
}

next();

function Ball(x, y, vx, vy, r, color) {
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    vx: vx,
    vy: vy,
    r: r,
    color: color
  }
};

function updateBall(b) {
  b.x += b.vx;
  b.y += b.vy;
  
  if (b.y <= b.r ||
      b.y >= cvs.height - b.r) {
     b.vy *= -0.5; 
  }
};

function drawBall(b) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = b.color;
  ctx.arc(b.x, b.y, b.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fill();
}

function updateFrame(balls) {
   balls.forEach(updateBall); 
}

function drawFrame(balls) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);
  balls.forEach(drawBall);
};
```

```html
<canvas width="300" height="150" style="background: #454545"></canvas>
<button onclick="next()">next</button>
<button onclick="loop()">run</button>
```

**In your case, I'm thinking this can only happen when there's a paddle collision AND a wall collision simultaneously.**

A quick-to-implement solution would be to check if the new position is valid *before* translating the ball position. If you don't want the precise location, you can place the ball at the point of collision. Note that this will produce a slightly off frame.

E.g.:

```
var newY = ballY + ballSpeedY;

// Top wall
if(newY <= 10) {
  ballY = 10;
  ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;  
}
// Bottom wall
else if(newY >= HEIGHT-10){
  ballY = HEIGHT - 10;
  ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;   
}
// No collision
else {
  ballY = newY;
}
```

**Update: a more detailed description of what can happen**

Let's say your ball collides with the top border of your canvas *and* with your paddle *in the same frame*.

First, you move the ball to the colliding position: `ballY += ballSpeedY;` Say your `ballY` is 4, and your `ballSpeedY` is -5, you'll position the ball to `-1`, inside the wall.

If this were to be the only collision, you should be okay. You flip the speed (`ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY`), so in the next frame, your ball should be back at `-1 + 5 = 4`, so `ballY` will be `4` again, and your ball will move towards `4 + 5 = 9` in the next frame.

Now a problem arises, when in the `-1` positioned frame, you collide with the paddle as well! When the paddle hits the ball, you modify the ballspeed: `ballSpeedY = deltaY / 5;`. If this turns out to be `< 1`, your ball won't be able to exit the wall in the next frame. Instead of `-1 + 5 = 4`, your ball will, for example, move to: `-1 + 0.5 = -0.5`.

Now, your ball won't be able to get back in to play, since the next frame will, again, calculate a collision and flip the speed. **This results in the bouncy, trembling effect you see when the ball gets stuck**.

A naive but pretty decent solution, is to only update the position of the ball to a *valid* position. I.e.: never to a colliding coordinate.

Comment: I understand when it occurs now, but still unclear why it happens. Can you please elaborate why the ball gets stuck. From your second code snippet, I saw that the two balls that got stuck jiggled before completely stopping. Why? Why were the other 2 balls fine?

Comment: The detailed explanation was a bit too long for a comment; I've edited my post to explain *exactly* what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
var animate = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60)
    };
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var width = 400;
var height = 600;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var player = new Player();
var computer = new Computer();
var ball = new Ball(200, 300);

var keysDown = {};

var render = function () {
    context.fillStyle = "#FF00FF";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    player.render();
    computer.render();
    ball.render();
};

var update = function () {
    player.update();
    computer.update(ball);
    ball.update(player.paddle, computer.paddle);
};

var step = function () {
    update();
    render();
    animate(step);
};

function Paddle(x, y, width, height) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x_speed = 0;
    this.y_speed = 0;
}

Paddle.prototype.render = function () {
    context.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
    context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
};

Paddle.prototype.move = function (x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
    this.x_speed = x;
    this.y_speed = y;
    if (this.x < 0) {
        this.x = 0;
        this.x_speed = 0;
    } else if (this.x + this.width > 400) {
        this.x = 400 - this.width;
        this.x_speed = 0;
    }
};

function Computer() {
    this.paddle = new Paddle(175, 10, 50, 10);
}

Computer.prototype.render = function () {
    this.paddle.render();
};

Computer.prototype.update = function (ball) {
    var x_pos = ball.x;
    var diff = -((this.paddle.x + (this.paddle.width / 2)) - x_pos);
    if (diff < 0 && diff < -4) {
        diff = -5;
    } else if (diff > 0 && diff > 4) {
        diff = 5;
    }
    this.paddle.move(diff, 0);
    if (this.paddle.x < 0) {
        this.paddle.x = 0;
    } else if (this.paddle.x + this.paddle.width > 400) {
        this.paddle.x = 400 - this.paddle.width;
    }
};

function Player() {
    this.paddle = new Paddle(175, 580, 50, 10);
}

Player.prototype.render = function () {
    this.paddle.render();
};

Player.prototype.update = function () {
    for (var key in keysDown) {
        var value = Number(key);
        if (value == 37) {
            this.paddle.move(-4, 0);
        } else if (value == 39) {
            this.paddle.move(4, 0);
        } else {
            this.paddle.move(0, 0);
        }
    }
};

function Ball(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.x_speed = 0;
    this.y_speed = 3;
}

Ball.prototype.render = function () {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(this.x, this.y, 5, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = "#000000";
    context.fill();
};

Ball.prototype.update = function (paddle1, paddle2) {
    this.x += this.x_speed;
    this.y += this.y_speed;
    var top_x = this.x - 5;
    var top_y = this.y - 5;
    var bottom_x = this.x + 5;
    var bottom_y = this.y + 5;

    if (this.x - 5 < 0) {
        this.x = 5;
        this.x_speed = -this.x_speed;
    } else if (this.x + 5 > 400) {
        this.x = 395;
        this.x_speed = -this.x_speed;
    }

    if (this.y < 0 || this.y > 600) {
        this.x_speed = 0;
        this.y_speed = 3;
        this.x = 200;
        this.y = 300;
    }

    if (top_y > 300) {
        if (top_y < (paddle1.y + paddle1.height) && bottom_y > paddle1.y && top_x < (paddle1.x + paddle1.width) && bottom_x > paddle1.x) {
            this.y_speed = -3;
            this.x_speed += (paddle1.x_speed / 2);
            this.y += this.y_speed;
        }
    } else {
        if (top_y < (paddle2.y + paddle2.height) && bottom_y > paddle2.y && top_x < (paddle2.x + paddle2.width) && bottom_x > paddle2.x) {
            this.y_speed = 3;
            this.x_speed += (paddle2.x_speed / 2);
            this.y += this.y_speed;
        }
    }
};

document.body.appendChild(canvas);
animate(step);

window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    keysDown[event.keyCode] = true;
});

window.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
    delete keysDown[event.keyCode];
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kHJr6/2/